# Why do different sites list different lengths of the lower deck bulk cargo compartment for the A330-300?

Tags: cargo, airbus-a330

From the following two links for Airbus A330-300, the length of "lower deck bulk cargo compartment" has two different values.

a) [Air China](http://www.airchinacargo.com/en/index.php?section=0-0149-0155-0176-0266) lists the value as 511 cm

b) [Airbus](http://www.aircraft.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/tech_data/AC/Airbus-AC_A330-Dec16.pdf) (see pg. 112) lists the value as 404 cm

Why?

Comment: The Airbus document says: `NOTE:
APPROXIMATE DIMENSIONS DEPENDING ON AIRCRAFT CONFIGURATION.`

Comment: It is interesting they list the same usable volume though.

Comment: fooot, you are right, in Airbus link we are referring about, there is note which declares the dimensions are approximate. But, about "..they list the same usable volume though.", considering only the two links called above, I can see that volumes value is provided only by airchinacargo.com/en/index.php?section=0-0149-0155-0176-0266 and it's not provided by by http://www.aircraft.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/tech_data/AC/Airbus-AC_A330-Dec16.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Some airlines have different specs. I can't comment on the examples you've given but one example I have encountered is on the A340-300.

The airline I worked for had conventional LD3 loading where the cans were loaded in pairs but for a while we had an A340 leased in from Swiss or Sabena (cant really remember which as it was more than 10 years ago) which had an additional LD3 position on the centreline of the aircraft in the space that would usually be available for bulk loading.

On thing which could affect the size of the bulk compartment is the location and number of toilets on the passenger deck. The plumbing usually lives under the floor.

Note the airbus site mentions that dimensions are approximate.

Comment: Thank you Anilv. So, the conclusion I have to understand is that, in dependance of the Customer the in the same Aircraft model, the size of the empty space usable for cargo hold could be often variated often by Manufacturer? But in that case everytime the engineering offices have to approve a modification in design that Hypoteticaly could affect the structure?

Comment: The empty space usable for cargo is constant. It is only how the space is used. Eg is it loaded as bulk (loose items) or in a ULD.